# Where do we learn that students are like offspring?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, torah-study, quotations

Is there a quote in the Talmud that says something like "anyone who teaches a child Torah is like he is his parent?"

Comment: See also [Baba Metzia 85b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.85a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): Anyone who teaches Torah to the son of another merits to sit and study in the heavenly academy

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this appears in the Talmud in [Sanhedrin 19b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=19b&format=pdf):

> אמר רבי שמואל בר נחמני א"ר יונתן כל המלמד בן חבירו תורה מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו ילדו שנאמר ואלה תולדות אהרן ומשה וכתיב ואלה שמות בני אהרן לומר לך אהרן ילד ומשה לימד לפיכך נקראו על שמו
>
> R. Samuel b. Nahmani said in R. Jonathan's name: He who teaches the son of his neighbour the Torah, Scripture ascribes it to him as if he had begotten him, as it says, Now, these are the generations of Aaron and Moses; whilst further on it is written, These are the names of the sons of Aaron: thus teaching thee that Aaron begot and Moses taught them; hence they are called by his name. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_19.html#PARTb))

Answer (score 0):

If you have engaged in the reproductive process and have not seen fruit from your efforts someone else’s child may be considered like your child with respect to your teaching of them. However, if you do not attempt to reproduce, you are considered without children and dead even if you have taught others.

[פתח עינים, ברכות כ](https://www.sefaria.org/Petach_Einayim_on_Berakhot.20a.3)

> משום דלא עסקת בפו"ר כלומר דאם עסקת ולא הי"ל (לך) בנים אף דבעלמא מי שאין לו בנים חשוב כמת אתה מכיון שלמדת תורה הרבה תלמידיך הם בניך כמ"ש כל המלמד בן חבירו כאלו ילדו וכתיב אלה תולדות אהרן ומשה. אבל עתה דלא איעסקת אף דיש לך תלמידים דלמד ולימד כמ"ש סוף פ"ק דקמא מ"מ אתה חשוב כמת בעון דלא איעסקת והיינו דאצטריך לומר כי מת אתה אף דיש לך תלמידים